# Grunt and NPM, package all production dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, npm-install

I am unsure when the way the NPM installs dependencies changed.
In the past I remember that if in my `project.json` I had a dependency on "abc", which in turn would depend on "xyz", a `npm install` would result in something like:

```
package.json
node_modules/
    abc/
        node_modules/
            xyz/
    some-dev-dep/
```

When packaging my node project to be used by AWS Lambda, I would have to include that `node_modules` structure (less any dev-dependencies that were there). I would use Grunt for my packaging, so I wrote this handy thing to help me get all production dependencies into this zip (extracting part of my gruntfile.js):

```
function getDependencies(pkg) {
    return Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
        .map(function(val) { return val + '/**'; });
}

var config = {
    compress: {
        prod: {
            options: {
                archive: 'public/lambda.zip'
            },
            files: [
                { src: 'index.js', dest: '/' },
                { expand: true, cwd: 'node_modules/', src: getDependencies(pkg), dest: '/node_modules' }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

This would work because dependencies of my dependencies were nested.
Recently (or maybe not-so-recently) this has changed (I am unsure when as I was using very old version of NPM and updated it recently).
Now if I depend on "abc" which in turn depends on "xyz" I will get:

```
node_modules/
    abc/
    xyz/
    some-dev-dep/
```

As you can see, my way of getting only production dependencies just won't work.
Is there any easy way to get only list of production dependencies (together with sub-dependencies) within grunt job?
I could do it using recursive function scanning for my dependencies, and then checking `project.json` files of those and then searching for sub-dependencies etc. This approach seems like a lot of hassle that is possibly a common scenario for many projects...

Comment: Use NVM so you can use NPM v2 when installing your dependencies. Then you'll have the old nested structure for your node_modules directory and your grunt script will work again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that returns an array of the production dependency module names. (Note: you might need to have the 'npm' module installed locally in your project for this to work.)

```js
/**
 * Returns an array of the node dependencies needed for production.
 * See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls for info on the 'npm ls' command.
*/
var getProdDependencies = function(callback) {
  require('child_process').exec('npm ls --prod=true --parseable=true', undefined,
      function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        var array = stdout.split('\n');
        var nodeModuleNames = [];

        array.forEach(function(line) {
          var index = line.indexOf('node_modules');
          if (index > -1) {
            nodeModuleNames.push(line.substr(index + 13));
          }
        });

        callback(nodeModuleNames);
      });
};
```

Comment: This is excatly what i need, that `ls --prod=true --parseable=true`. Thanks.

Comment: @psulek, I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This change was introduced with the release of npm 3 (see [npm v3 Dependency Resolution](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3)).

It's not exactly clear why you need to use Grunt at all. If what you want to do is get only production dependencies you can simply run:

`npm install --production`

With the `--production` flag, all dev dependencies will be ignored. The same is also true if the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to *'production'*.

Comment: I know I can run this, but I can't use that to get only production dependencies in my Grunt job. For now I am copying files I want to zip/rpm to a `dist/` directory and run `npm install --production` there, then Grunt does the packaging into zip and/or RPM.